# Is it a correct way to compare Intents?

Tags: android

Is it a correct way to compare `Intents`? I never get in to the if/else regardless the incoming `Intent` is `android.Intent.action.VIEW` (the value intent.getAction() returns):

```
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction()); // -> android.Intent.action.VIEW
            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                ShowToast.showToast(this, "Something..."); // Never get here
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                showResults(query);
            }
        }
```

**Update**: Why does the `intent.getAction()` returns `android.Intent.action.VIEW` (capital 'i') while it should return `android.intent.action.VIEW` as in [specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)?

Comment: something is wrong, the correct string should be "android.intent.action.VIEW" with lowercase "i" in "intent".

Comment: @Joe, indeed, just noticed that either. Very strange...

Comment: see if you can find the code that sends the Intent, it is likely that there is a mistake there.

Comment: @Joe, yeah, I found where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where the capital 'i' came from. As long as I'm using the `SearchView` I specify what `Intent` to be used when new `Activity` would start by myself, so I just made a mistake here:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/appname"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:searchSuggestAuthority="my.package.dataproviders.TicketSuggestionProvider"
            android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://my.package.dataproviders.TicketSuggestionProvider/titleslist"
            android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.Intent.action.VIEW" // HERE IT IS
            android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?">
</searchable>
```

Comment: You probably just copied the mistake from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html - they use the capital 'i' 2 out of 5 times there. And so did I when I copied a line of XML from that page.